# Vectorized dictionary in Python

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any package in Python that provides a dictionary for vectorized access with NumPy arrays? I am looking for something like this:

```
>>> vector_dict = VectorizedDict({1: "One",
...                               2: "Two",
...                               3: "Three"},
...                               dtype_key=int, dtype_val="U5")
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3]),
>>> b = vector_dict[a]
>>> print(type(b))
np.ndarray
>>> print(b)
["One", "Two", "Three"]
```

Although this result would also be possible to achieve by iterating over the array elements, the iteration approach would be rather inefficient for large arrays.

EDIT:

For small dictionaries I use the following approach:

```
for key, val in my_dict.items():
    b[a == key] = val
```

Although the boolean masking is quite efficient when iterating over small dictionaries, it is time consuming for large dictionaries (thousands of key-value-paris).

Comment: It would be useful to have some benchmarking data so we can test solutions with realistic inputs.

Comment: Did either of the posted solution work for you?

Comment: How much slower would it be to use: `b = [ my_dict[ia] for ia in a ]`?

Comment: @JLT I performed a quick benchmark, where I compared a `dict` with an `ndarray`, that I used to map integers to integers. The result: the `ndarray` runs 250 times faster than the `dict`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a vectorized python dictionary/set that efficiently stores data and uses numpy arrays. Most combinations of numpy datatypes are supported.

You can find the project and documentation here: https://github.com/atom-moyer/getpy

Comment: Can you post the actual answer (instead of url)?

Comment: are you going to extend support for windows users? this seems like a really good idea.

Answer (score 7):

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) data structures implement this functionality for 1D ([`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html)), 2D ([`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)) and 3D ([`pd.Panel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html)) data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(data=['One', 'Two', 'Three'], index=[1, 2, 3])
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = s[a]
print(b.values)
['One' 'Two' 'Three']
```

For higher-dimensional structures, you have [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/).

Comment: Do you know if this approach is C-accelerated or if it uses internally a pure Python iteration over the input array or dictionary?

Comment: @PadixKey Both Pandas and xarray arebuilt on NumPy, so they use fast vectorized operations for most things. These data structures are supported with indices that allow for fast look-up operations. [Here](https://www.slideshare.net/wesm/a-look-at-pandas-design-and-development) are some slides about the design of Pandas.

Comment: I wish there were a more elegant way but this sure does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two approaches -

```
def lookup_dict_app1(vector_dict, a):
    k = np.array(list(vector_dict.keys()))
    v = np.array(list(vector_dict.values()))
    sidx = k.argsort()
    return v[sidx[np.searchsorted(k,a,sorter=sidx)]].tolist()

def lookup_dict_app2(vector_dict, a):
    k = np.array(list(vector_dict.keys()))
    v = vector_dict.values()
    sidx = k.argsort()
    indx = sidx[np.searchsorted(k,a,sorter=sidx)]
    out = [v[i] for i in indx]
    return out
```

If the keys obtained with `vector_dict.keys()` are already sorted, skip the `argsort()` and indexing with `sidx` steps. Or, we can do a simple check and get the modified versions, like so -

```
def lookup_dict_app1_mod(vector_dict, a):
    k = np.array(list(vector_dict.keys()))
    v = np.array(list(vector_dict.values()))
    if (k[1:] >= k[:-1]).all():
        return v[np.searchsorted(k,a)].tolist()
    else:
        sidx = k.argsort()
        return v[sidx[np.searchsorted(k,a,sorter=sidx)]].tolist()

def lookup_dict_app2_mod(vector_dict, a):
    k = np.array(list(vector_dict.keys()))
    v = vector_dict.values()
    if (k[1:] >= k[:-1]).all():
        return [v[i] for i in np.searchsorted(k,a)]
    else:
        sidx = k.argsort()
        indx = sidx[np.searchsorted(k,a,sorter=sidx)]
        return [v[i] for i in indx]
```

Sample run -

```
In [166]: vector_dict = {1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 0:'Zero'}

In [167]: a = np.array([1,2,3,2,3,1])

In [168]: lookup_dict_app1(vector_dict, a)
Out[168]: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Two', 'Three', 'One']

In [169]: lookup_dict_app2(vector_dict, a)
Out[169]: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Two', 'Three', 'One']
```

Comment: I think this method has quite an overhead compared to a truly vectorized dictionary, due to the conversion into lists, value sorting and the binary search

Comment: @PadixKey Typically how many keys are you expecting in your dictionary? How many elements would you have in the array `a`? With a large number of elements in `a` as compared to the number of keys in dict, it won't be too bad working with that small dict.

Comment: There could be thousands of key-value pairs in the dictionary and thousands of elements in the array.

Comment: @PadixKey We could skip the conversion to array for values. We would need it for the keys though, as the proposed approach is based on sorting and it's efficient to work with arrays. Check out the updated codes.

Comment: Love pure Numpy/Vectorized approaches.

Comment: @Kasramvd Me, too but I fear that NumPy does not have a proper solution for this.

Comment: @Divakar I already have an approach for small dictionaries using boolean masks, that avoids creation of intermediary lists and binary searches (I updated my question). The problem are large dictionaries.

Comment: @PadixKey Think you could time these at your end and check out the performance on these different strategies for yourself.

Comment: @PadixKey Would the output be a list or an array? Looking at the question, it seems it would be an array, but can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, I need an ndarray.

Comment: @PadixKey Then, you can skip `.tolist()` at the end of the proposed approaches.